# Facebook/Meta API child pages cannot retrieve assigned_users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Trying to build an app for work to automate the management of Facebook pages.

The setup we currently have is as follows:

- 1 main page
- 243 locations/stores (each with a child page)

The goal is to be able to list all accounts that have been given at any point access to post, moderate, impersonate the page through Facebook.

My dev account and the system user account both have permissions to manage "Everything" - given through the Meta business suite.

As it currently stands, I can retrieve `assigned_users` for the parent page.

When trying to do the same for a child location I get the following (using `me` as the access_token belonged to the location) but also tried the location id with the other types of tokens:

Query:

```
me/assigned_users?business=[BUSINESS_ID]
```

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Added a separate main page to the account and tried the same thing and it seems that until my user is added to `assigned_users` I cannot list the other users. Fair enough. Tried to add both my user and the admin system user to `assigned_users` of a location only to be met with the below:

Query:

```
/[locationid]/asssigned_users?business=[BUSINESS_ID]&user=[USER_ID]
```

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) You do not have permission to perform this action. This action requires that you can MODIFY_BUSINESS_ASSETS on a managing business account.  Or it requires that you can ADMINISTER on this object Note: to use do this action on behalf of a business account the \"business\" field must be set.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "AU7hjxCFsGNB0fuxhY5odBl
"
  }
}
```

All these queries are in Graph explorer and I tried all the access_tokens that I can get there: my account, system user, main page, location page etc.

Does anyone have any idea how the permissions can be added - seeing as the account already is added with permissions to manage everything?

Why would the access not be inherited to the location pages seeing as they belong to the main page as a parent and I can list the users there?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey! Have you found a way around this? I'm facing the same problem with the `https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/${adsAccountID}/assigned_users` endpoint.